POST upload: curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
I get curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application when uploading (with POST) a file with -F "file=@$file", in bash.

From the curl manpage:

If filename/path contains ',' or ';', it must be quoted by
double-quotes like:
curl -F "file=@\"local,file\";filename=\"name;in;post\"" example.com
or
curl -F 'file=@"local,file";filename="name;in;post"' example.com
Note that if a filename/path is quoted by double-quotes, any
double-quote or backslash within the filename must be escaped by
backslash.

So -F "file=@$file" should be:
-F "file=@\"$file\""

